# Transformer and electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

In transformer , the primary induces the emf in secondary , then why changing flux in secondary doesn't induce in primary . But if it induces doesn't there be oscillation of induction ?

Comment: Question doesn't seem to be entirely clear but here goes: A "changing flux in the secondary" due to current flowing in the secondary circuit does cause an induced EMF in the primary. So, yes, there is coupling in both directions between the primary and secondary circuits. The input electrical impedance of a transformer whose primary coil is being driven by a current source or voltage source will change depending on whether the wires of the secondary coil are, for example, shorted together or open. If you have a small transformer to play with you can verify that yourself.

Comment: Years ago, after living in Europe, I moved back to the US. I had a nice stereo system running off European power. The local electronics dump (random parts store, actual called the Electronics Dump in the local language) had various transformers used by US service folks coming from the US to power their stuff. I bought one (real cheap) and changed the plug/sockets to go the other way around. Ran that stereo 'backwards' for many years. The moral of the story: primary and secondary are more defined by you than the transformer.